# Simulate Poisson distribution with different lambdas using inverse CDF method

Tags: r, regression, simulation, poisson, inverse-transform

I have to generate Poisson regression, for that I want to use inverse CDF method. I am following [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27443/generate-data-samples-from-poisson-regression) post to generate data. But it isn't based on inverse cdf method. The post has following code

```
>   #sample size
> n <- 10
>   #regression coefficients
> beta0 <- 1
> beta1 <- 0.2
>   #generate covariate values
> x <- runif(n=n, min=0, max=1.5)
>   #compute mu's
> mu <- exp(beta0 + beta1 * x)
>   #generate Y-values
> y <- rpois(n=n, lambda=mu)
>   #data set
> data <- data.frame(y=y, x=x)
> data
```

I do not want to use the r built in function `rpois`. I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72984397/trying-to-simulate-poisson-samples-using-inverse-cdf-method-but-my-r-function-pr) post which does utilize the method only for one lambda. Now, how can I generate Poisson distribution with inverse cdf method for a variety of lambda?
N.B. [This useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74004083/simulations-of-poisson-distributions-with-different-sample-sizes-and-lambdas) post provides code for variety of sample sizes, I do not want that.

Comment: why not use rpois?

Comment: I want to use inverse cdf to manually generate Poisson.

Comment: There's an R implementation of an inverse Poisson cdf in the first answer to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/296818/equation-for-inverse-poisson-cdf). Does that do what you need?

Answer (score 1):

The answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/296818/equation-for-inverse-poisson-cdf) is elegant and fast, but if you don't care about efficiency then

```r
my_rpois <- function(n, lambda) {
   qpois(runif(n), lambda)
}
```

should work to implement the inverse-CDF method.  (`lambda` can be a vector)

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to not use qpois, dpois, rpois? I mean only utilize the uniform distribution.

Comment: See @jblood94's answer. More generally, it would be helpful if you gave more detail in your question (e.g., you said `rpois()` was disallowed but you didn't say that you wanted to avoid the other `*pois()` functions), and context - if we knew *why* you were avoiding the built-in functions (homework? learning exercise?) that would help us give a more useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying my answer in your linked post to take a vector of rates:

```
rpois2 <- function(n, lambda) {
  u <- runif(n)
  i <- 0L
  k <- integer(n)
  p <- exp(-lambda)
  f <- p
  idx <- 1:n
  
  while (length(idx)) {
    bln <- u[idx] < f[idx]
    k[idx[bln]] <- i
    idx <- idx[!bln]
    p[idx] <- lambda[idx]*p[idx]/(i <- i + 1L)
    f[idx] <- f[idx] + p[idx]
  }
  
  k
}
```

Testing:

```
n <- 10
beta0 <- 1
beta1 <- 0.2
x <- runif(n=n, min=0, max=1.5)
mu <- exp(beta0 + beta1 * x)
system.time({y <- replicate(1e5, rpois2(n, mu))})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    1.87    0.01    1.89
system.time({z <- replicate(1e5, rpois(n, mu))})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.35    0.06    0.40
data.frame(
  mean.y = rowMeans(y),
  mean.z = rowMeans(z),
  var.y = apply(y, 1, var),
  var.z = apply(z, 1, var)
)
#>     mean.y  mean.z    var.y    var.z
#> 1  2.82232 2.81855 2.826438 2.814754
#> 2  2.89834 2.91290 2.905394 2.914763
#> 3  3.41615 3.41951 3.416323 3.418016
#> 4  3.47183 3.47874 3.473361 3.460303
#> 5  3.26286 3.25541 3.261857 3.244148
#> 6  3.28565 3.28160 3.269067 3.288014
#> 7  3.49654 3.48724 3.485543 3.484132
#> 8  3.59513 3.60039 3.596586 3.604258
#> 9  3.39864 3.38836 3.378420 3.388850
#> 10 2.89590 2.89425 2.887852 2.901856
```